# Maintain Angle Between Bones While Rotating

Tags: bones, constraints

I would like to rotate the green bones around the cursor like in the video but with a constant angle (90°) between the green bones.
I've already tried the limit rotation constraint with no success.
Also the locking of the x,y & z of the IK like it is explained in [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/215570/setting-angles-between-bones) does not work.
How can I limit set an orientation constraint between these bones?

Cheers!

[image]

[image]