# How to properly apply rotation on pose bones

Tags: python, pose-mode, mathematics, quaternion

First off, gonna admit it and say i absolutely suck at geometry and at Blender's scripting, so excuse if i made dumb mistakes.

I have a quaternion and a position, i need to apply them to the pose bones, i've tried everything from:

```
translationQuaternion = mathutils.Quaternion((W, X, Y, Z))
poseBone.rotation_quaternion = translationQuaternion
```

to

```
translationQuaternion = mathutils.Quaternion((W, X, Y, Z))
editMatrix = editBone.matrix.to_3x3()

R = translationQuaternion.to_matrix() @ editMatrix

poseBone.rotation_quaternion = R.to_quaternion()
poseBone.keyframe_insert("rotation_quaternion", frame=frameData.Key)
```

Nothing seems to work, i'll appreciate any help i have no idea how to fix it

Comment: does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214873/42221) help at all?  It's not your answer, but the discussion might be useful to you.

Comment: Will check it, thanks!